# Can't deploy exploded artifact

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, artifact

I can't deploy exploded artefact on TomCat 8.5, however non-exploded artefact deploys perfectly fine. Can anyone help what am I doing wrong?

I tried a lot to find the errors but I couldn't

so is there any way to find the errors ?

```
"C:\Tomcat 8\bin\catalina.bat" run
    [2016-12-11 12:59:18,702] Artifact Tech House Project:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Al7amed\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_Tech_House_Project_2"
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Tomcat 8"
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Tomcat 8\temp"
    Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102"
    Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Tomcat 8\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Tomcat 8\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jul 6 2016 08:43:30 UTC
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.4.0
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_102-b14
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Al7amed\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_Tech_House_Project_2
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Tomcat 8
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Al7amed\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_Tech_House_Project_2\conf\logging.properties
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Al7amed\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_Tech_House_Project_2
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Tomcat 8
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tomcat 8\temp
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.8 using APR version 1.5.2.
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.859 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016)
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.935 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.947 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.951 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.951 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.951 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 854 ms
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.969 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.970 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.975 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.978 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:19.978 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 27 ms
    Connected to server
    [2016-12-11 12:59:25,668] Artifact Tech House Project:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:27.200 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:27.260 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:27.387 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Dec 11 12:59:27 GST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:27.440 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:27.769 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:27.807 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion.performVersionChecks You are running with Spring Security Core 3.2.5.RELEASE
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:27.811 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.<init> Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.2.5.RELEASE
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:27.883 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.checkFilterChainOrder Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:28.083 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [ae.coder.DAO.impl.CartDAOImpl]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ae/coder/DAO/impl/CartDAOImpl.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:28.089 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [ae.coder.DAO.impl.CartDAOImpl]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ae/coder/DAO/impl/CartDAOImpl.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ae/coder/DAO/impl/CartDAOImpl.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:620)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:578)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:229)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
        ... 54 more

    11-Dec-2016 12:59:28.092 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:28.093 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/shop] startup failed due to previous errors
    [2016-12-11 12:59:28,115] Artifact Tech House Project:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:29.977 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat 8\webapps\manager
    11-Dec-2016 12:59:30.007 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Tomcat 8\webapps\manager has finished in 30 ms
```

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ae/coder/DAO/impl/CartDAOImpl.class]` should be the answer to the current stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

it might be cause of corrupted exploded application. check this resource [ae/coder/DAO/impl/CartDAOImpl.class] exist in your exploded directory.